# Error sending JSON over webscket

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, websocket

i have this small chat app in javascript and node and i am trying to send a simple JSON object over websocket, but it is displaying an error related to the "JSON.parse" i am doing in the server side. I've tried to change the code, but nothing seems to work. Why could this be?
my operating system is windows 8.1 and i am using firefox and chrome.

```
undefined:1
undefined
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u
    at Object.parse (native)
    at WebSocketConnection.<anonymous> (C:\Users\*****\Documents\simple
_chat\server.js:39:22)
```

here is the code on the client side

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:1234');

    function sendMessage(){
        var message = document.getElementById('message').value;
        var message_send ={
            name_:"WHATEVER",
            message_:message
        }
        socket.send(JSON.stringify(message_send));
    }

    socket.addEventListener("message", function(e){
        var msg = e.data;
        console.log(e);
        document.getElementById('chatlog').innerHTML+='<br>'+msg;
    })
```

here is the server code:

```
var count = 0;
var client ={};

var websocket = require('websocket').server;
wsServer = new websocket({httpServer:server});

wsServer.on('request',function(r){
    var connection = r.accept(null, r.origin);
    var id = count++;
    client[id]=connection
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Connection accepted [' + id + ']');

    connection.on('message', function (message) {
        var k = JSON.parse(message.data);
        var message_ = k.content_
        var name_ = k.name_;
        console.log(name_ +"  "+message_);
        for(var i in client){
            client[i].sendUTF(name_+":  "+message_);
        }
    });

    connection.on('close', function (reasonCode, description) {
        delete client[id];
        console.log((new Date()) + ' Peer ' + connection.remoteAddress + ' disconnected.');
    })
})
```

Comment: What is the raw value returned from the http request?

Comment: so the error says `u`, but your code doesn't have any variables called `u`, can you help us out by pinpointing where things *actually* go wrong, and what the JSON is that you're trying to read in, whether it can be network resolved (404,403,etc.) and if it resolves, whether that's valid json? You can't just use JSON.parse, you always need to wrap it in a try/catch because it'll throw on bad input. Add the try/catch, and see whether the code throws, and if so, what the error and input was.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that error appears because `message.data` has value `undefined`, which is not a valid JSON value.

The question, thus, is "why is `message.data` undefined?", and if I remember correctly it's because the data sent over Socket.io is in `message` and not `message.data`.

**TL;DR** Replace `var k = JSON.parse(message.data);` with `var k = JSON.parse(message);`

PS: with Socket.io you don't need to manually JSON stringify/parse objects, as the API does that for you. You can just pass the object